# How to implement horizontal scroll slider in html for a series of images?

Tags: html

I want to make a horizontal scroll slider for a series of images. I just need a single row of images (they must not repeat in y-axis).
I have this very simple code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; height:100px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
<img src="01.png" style="float:left; padding:2px">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is that the list of images repeats in y-axis, which is undesirable. 
Sorry for posting the lengthy list of images. Please help.

Comment: discover css. take out all the styles? img{display: block; padding: 2px;} or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple way to handle this is to add some styles to your existing div, and add an additional div inside of it (around the images).
First, add the following styles to your existing div:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
width: <whatever width in % you want>;
```

Then add another  (or other container element) inside of your original div, but around the images:

```
<body>
  <div ...>
    <div>
      <img ... >
...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Finally, add a width to this new div, that is much wider than that of its containing div.  This should cause everything to scroll properly.

FYI: this is hacky, and works if you know exactly how many images you will have so you can get the width of that internal  correct.  IF you make that inner width too small, you won't see all the images.

Comment: i would suggest same but width in %  ( e.g. div being say 100% and img being 10%) ....

Comment: It has been sorted now: Did this and its done <div style="overflow-x:scroll;  white-space:nowrap">. I appreciate your efforts. :) Thanks a lot...